# Change color of LI by its ID (materialize,Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I have many list-items(li's) and every single one has its own ID. Is there a way to change the color of a specific Li by its ID for example by a button or something(pls in Javascript). Thanks for any help!

```
  const li = `
  <li id= "${doc_id}">
    <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4 right-align"> ${name} ${distance}km von dir entfernt (${Ort},${PLZ}) </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>lol${name} lat</span>
    
  </li>
`;
```

Comment: The `</a>` in that string looks incorrect.

Comment: The second `div` is never closed, that is going to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this where you loop over and use setAttribute to apply a class.

```js
const ul = document.getElementById("list");
const items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
console.log("+++", items);

for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  items[i].setAttribute("class", "test");
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    Test
  </li>

  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
  <li>
    Test
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Setting the "class" directly like that can stomp on other code that may want to add/remove classes independent of this purpose.

Comment: I mean, I'd be using react if it were me. No idea what his use case is, just demonstrating one way it can be done.

Comment: Almost all modern browsers have the `.classList` property, which has its own add/remove API.

Comment: Would be great if you wrote an answer demonstrating it